# Counting days between two days excluding weekend (Saturday and Sunday) in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive, aqua-data-studio

the problem is simple, I have two dates and count all days between them by using datediff() function.

E.g.: datediff('23/08/2023', '30/08/2023') returns 7, but it should return 5, because 26-27/08/2023 are weekend days.

Do You know any function or have a practical solution how to count it? The simpler, the better. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Technical-Tips-Tricks/How-to-Count-Only-Weekdays-Between-Two-Dates/ta-p/587598) seems to be a pretty good solution.

In your case that would result in:

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(day, '2023/08/23', '2023/08/30') + 1 -
DATEDIFF(week, '2023/08/23', DATEADD(day, 1, '2023/08/30')) -
DATEDIFF(week, '2023/08/23', '2023/08/30')
AS DateDiff;
```

When executing this resulted in 6 weekdays which seems to be correct: 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 30.

Comment: Sorry, but key words "day" and "week" are not recognized by my editor in Aqua Data Studio. DATEADD should also be replaced by DATE_ADD.

Comment: Can you try adding single quotes or double quotes around `day` and `week`?

Comment: I've tried and I got an error: Arguments length mismatch ''2023-08-30'': datediff() requires 2 argument, got 3 what is obvious.